# Нужно объединить три переменные в одну переменную и сделать подобный вывод 5 * 8 или 4 - 2 или 8 + 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
import random
a = random.randrange(2,10)
b = random.choice("+" "-" "*")
c = random.randrange(2,10)
d = (a + b + c)
print(d)
//код выдает ошибку в 5 строке
```

Comment: Естественно ошибка будет. Вы строку **b** с числами **а** и **b** складываете

Answer (score 1):

`random.choice("+" "-" "*")` - формально это не ошибка. Вы знаете что компилятор Python складывает строки если они идут подряд? Ваш код работает как `random.choice("+-*")`. Проблемы будут если вы захотите операторы из нескольких символов.

`a + b + c` - складывать строки и числа нельзя. Но и не надо: функция `print` сама разберётся.

```
import random

a = random.randrange(2, 10)
b = random.choice(('+', '-', '*', '**'))
c = random.randrange(2, 10)
print(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в `a` и `c` у вас числа, а в `b` строка. Нужно преобразовать `a` и `c` в строки:

```
import random
a = str(random.randrange(2,10))
b = random.choice("+" "-" "*")
c = str(random.randrange(2,10))
d = (a + b + c)
print(d)
```

Comment: спасибо сработало